# Android - disable notifydatasetchanged for existing items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

Is it possible to disable the refresh of the RecyclerView for the items already existing ?
Because when I refresh the RecyclerView after adding new items, we can see visually the refreshing of the RecyclerView.
I think we can see the refreshing because of the ImageView in each items.

So I want to disable `notifydatasetchanged`for existing items.

Comment: no you don't. what you want is keep your images cached.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want

Comment: I recommend you to study about [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). it's a good library to cache images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `RecyclerView`, you should use [notifyItemRangeInserted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)) method (and friends) to refresh only items that were added, instead of `notifyDatasetChanged`. You can also refresh only items that have changed (`notifyItemChanged`) or that an item has moved (`notifyItemMoved`)